# Get the very last row in a table, although it isn't scrolled into current sight

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, cypress

I have a table which contains many rows. Only the nth-oldest rows are visible. The newer rows are hidden and one has got to use a scrollbar to move them into sight.

I have written the following Cypress-statement:

```
cy.get("span.class1.class2").last().click();
```

It returns the last row, which is visible, when the view becomes shown. Marked red in the screenshot.

[image]

But what I like to have is the **very last row** in the table. Marked blue.

[image]

**Is that possible with a simple Cypress-statement?**

Or do I have to move the scrollbar down first? 
If so: **How can I scroll downwards using Cypress?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `parent` class of  that table and you could try using `scrollTo()`option.

**cypress documentation:**
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto.html#Syntax

Examples:

```
cy.scrollTo(0, 500)                     // Scroll the window 500px down
cy.get('.sidebar').scrollTo('bottom')   // Scroll 'sidebar' to its bottom
```

There is another option called `.scrollIntoView()`, but I think in your cases the scrollTo() might help.

Comment: The second possibility with "scrollTo bottom" has worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know that . I think, `cy.scrollTo(0, 500)` is just an example,   instead of 500 if you increase the `px`  in your case, that will also work i think. Increase to `cy.scrollTo(0, 800) or cy.scrollTo(0, 1000)` and see what is happening.